# C# Compile .NET Core 3.0 to Native Code through Visual Studio 2019

Tags: .net-core, .net-core-3.0, corert

I am using Visual Studio 2019 with C# 8.0 and my project is based on this sample: https://github.com/dotnet/corert/tree/master/samples/HelloWorld

When I open a command prompt and navigate in my solution folder I use the following command to compile in native code:

> dotnet publish -c release -r win-x64

This works great.

However compiling/building in Visual Studio 2019 (and not using cmd) won't generate the native code. In the output window there is no step "Generating native code".

Here is my .csproj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <AssemblyVersion>1.0.1234</AssemblyVersion>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
    <Platforms>x64</Platforms>
    <DebugType>none</DebugType>
    <DebugSymbols>false</DebugSymbols>
    <LangVersion>8.0</LangVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.DotNet.ILCompiler" Version="1.0.0-alpha-*" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="12.0.1" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: My guess is this is only supported via `dotnet publish` currently.

Comment: @IanKemp any way to execute dotnet publish within Visual Studio 2019?

Comment: Try running it from the post-build event (project > properties > Build Events > Post-build event command-line).

Comment: @IanKemp That would mean building the project twice? Maybe there is an entry in .csproj that would compile it directly with VS2019?

Answer (score 0):

You can publish it in the post-build event without re-compilation
`dotnet publish --no-build --no-restore /p:NativeLib=Shared -r win-x64 -c release`